# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child. when using react-flow-editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed this tutorial to make a react-flow-editor component:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flow-editor

Then I adapted it for my project as the above one uses typescript. Below is my code:

```
import { Config, Editor, Node } from 'react-flow-editor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Workflow extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nodes: [
          {
            id: 'Node 1',
            name: 'First Node',
            payload: { h1: 'hello' },
            inputs: [{
              connection: [], name: 'input 1'
            }],
            outputs: []
          }],
      config: {
        resolver: function(payload) {
          if ( payload.type === '') return <h2 />;
          return (
            <p>{payload}</p>
          );
        },
        connectionType: 'bezier',
        grid: true,
        demoMode: true,
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor config={this.state.config} nodes={this.state.nodes} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Workflow;
```

When running it, I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, payload, inputs, outputs}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219980/discussion-on-question-by-k-smith-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-o).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer.
The issue is that you try to render a complex object directly with react.

Try this fix:

```
- <p>{payload}</p>
+ <p>{payload.payload.h1}</p>
```

This should solve the issue.